# Where can I find a replacement tub diverter spigot for an old unit (with photos)

Tags: bathroom, spigot

I have an old style tub spigot that when you push the spigot to make the water come out the shower instead of going into the tub, 3/4 of the water goes to the shower head and the rest goes down the drain.

[image: Old style tub spigot. Where can I purchase a replacement?]

---

[image: The spigot screws into the center.]

The spigot screws into the center.

---

[image: full spigot]

here is a photo of the full spigot.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the problem? Do you mean you push a lever/knob ON the spigot? By "down the drain" do you mean "into the tub and down its drain"?

Comment: Please post a photo where we can see the rest of the spout and another of the wall where the spout used to be.

Comment: I have those, usually there is some calc deposits inside, and I spray some WD40 inside to make it move

Comment: The spigot doesn't seat properly because it is old so the water drains out the spigot as well as the shower.  I will try to post more photos.

Comment: Sounds to me like a problem with your diverter valve.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem with the diverter valve.  I am hoping someone can provide a link where I can purchase a replacement spigot.  I have contacted four different plumbing supply companies and have searched online and haven't found a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

As you have removed it, you *presumably* have a pipe coming out of the wall at the tub. The measurements and type of that pipe will determine what spouts are compatible for replacements without further replumbing.

Replacements are pretty generic, once you sort out "smooth pipe .vs. threaded pipe" and "how far out from the face of the wall?" you just need one that attaches the same way to the same size pipe, and at the same distance from the wall.

Comment: It is a threaded pipe.